# Firefox translate3d messes with select input

Tags: javascript, css, firefox

I am designing a website based on a theme that uses `translate3d`, which messes with the select dropdown window.

```
<select>
    <option value="Biały">Biały</option>
    <option value="Czarny">Czarny</option>
    <option value="Czerwony">Czerwony</option>
    <option value="Żółty">Żółty</option>
</select>
```

Basically when I open up the list in Firefox, the whole list is **shifted** to the left like this:

[image]

EDIT------------------
added a [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/silatixepu/edit?html,output) click the About tab

Comment: Its kinda complicated to make a JSfiddle, project is multifile
if you have firebug, just edit one of the sections and replace it with the select button 
http://themes.webdevia.com/tita-wp/demo-6/

Comment: I have created a JSbin: http://jsbin.com/silatixepu/edit?html,output
click the about tab

Comment: Doesn't seem to have that issue in Chrome 49 on Mac 10.11.2.

Comment: I guess, i havent made that clear enaugh but this problem only occurs in firefox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure this is what you are looking for, but the root issue is not the rotate itself.  It's that the container has a transform.  This transform may be entirely unnecessary.  Instead of using a transform you can substitute absolute positioning.  You have to do so with the following:

```
#spaces-main{
  transform: none!important;
  position: absolute;
  left: 240px;
  right: 0;
  width: auto;
}
```

A horizontal scrollbar seems to appear on the original demo and my version, so I added this as well

```
body{
  overflow-x:hidden;
}
```

The tradeoff is that responsive may need adjusted and one or more transitions might not work as they did originally.  In any case, here is a demo with the dropdown now working correctly.

http://jsbin.com/karinajalu/1/edit?html,output

Instead of this solution, you might consider adding a styleable dropdown plugin.  It probably wouldn't experience the same issue and it would both nicer and more consistent across various browsers.  I have no recommendations on what plugin to use.

Comment: Thank you sooooo much, this has fixed the issue :)

Comment: @RadekWysocki You're welcome.  Glad I could help.